# Error in the parallel connection of voltage generators (cells)

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, circuit, circuit-diagram

I am having the following errors during the simulation of the model in the picture (the blocks cell, cell1, and cell2 contains the electrochemical model of a battery cell, by the way also trying to change these blocks with the built-in ConstantVoltage I got a similar error):

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18OB1.png)] 12:36:28 Symbolic Error
An independent subset of the model has imbalanced number of equations (180) and variables (177).
variables:

[2] 12:36:37 Translation Error
pre-optimization module clockPartitioning (simulation) failed.

[image: Parallel connection]

Do you know what is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to connect

1. ideal sources of potential variables (in this case voltages) in parallel or
2. ideal sources of flow (could be current sources) in series.

For the circuit in the screenshot, this will result in equation systems `cell.V` = `cell.V1` = `cell.V2` with all of the variables known and therefore resulting in an "imbalanced number of equations and variables.

What you need to do is make the sources non-ideal, which usually is closer to reality. For this you can e.g. add a inner resistance in series to all voltage sources. For current/flow sources this could be adding a parallel resistance to the source.

By the way: there is no point in connecting ideal voltage source in parallel, as each of them can supply infinite current without any drop in voltage...

Comment: Thank you Markus, I tried to work keeping in mind in kind reply. What I want to do is to connect cells both in series and in parallel and give to each cell as inputs a current value and a SOC value. So basically what in reality the resistance does, in my case is done by the value of current given to each cell. Do you think it is possible? Each cell model is based on a system of DAEs and I modeled the pos and neg pins using OnePort from MSL. I tried to modified OnePort to consider the connection between two pos pins but without success. Do you think this could be a good way to make it works?

Comment: If you DAE models a inner resistance it should be possible. For me, the question is, why you use a voltage source only. I guess the DAE describes some voltage source + resistance. If that is the case set the voltage at the pins directly without the voltage source and it should be fine. In any case, the DAE should create a relation between current and voltage to make the overall system work. But it is a bit difficult to judge without seeing the actual code...

Answer (score 1):

I notice two things:

1. All voltage sources are short-cirquited which gives contradictory equations (`v=V` and `v=0`). The variable names refer to the code of `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.ConstantVoltage`
2. The parallel voltage sources each try to set the voltage across the parallel sources.

Comment: Thank you Rene for your reply. Do you know how can make this work? I tried different ways to overcome the issues you highlighted in your reply but without success. Basically, what I want is to make work different generators connected in parallel and to measure the overall voltage and current.